# Why does running Google JavaScript Linter via Grunt fail?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jslint, lint, gjslint

We use [gjslinter](https://github.com/jmendiara/grunt-gjslint) with Grunt to lint all the js files in our project.

The configuration in Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
gjslint: {
    options: {
        flags: ['--disable 220,110,200'],
        reporter: {
            name: 'gjslint_xml',
            dest: '<%= pkg.docs %>/gjslint/gjslint.xml'
        }
    },
    all: {
        src: ['<%= pkg.src %>/assets/js/modules/**', '<%= pkg.src %>/assets/js/lib/jquery/plugins/jquery-hse/**']
    }
}
```

But when I start the linting it fails:

```
$ grunt gjslint Running "gjslint:all" (gjslint) task
Warning: Task "gjslint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Why? Paths should be correct. There are no more error messages or reports. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by following these steps (on Windows 10 here):

1. Installed Python2.7 https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Added Python installation directories `C:/Python27` as well as `C:/Python27/Scripts` to `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` env variables
3. Installed Google JavaScript Linter by running this in command line:

   `pip install https://github.com/google/closure-linter/zipball/master`
4. Changed reporter setting for Grunt:

(Gruntfile.js):

```
reporter: {
    name: 'console' //report to console
}
```

Now I am getting proper error messages in console when running `grunt gjslint`. It showed me that there was a min.js file which had some invalid code. So, I removed it from Gruntfile.js by adding an exception for min files:

```
src: [
  '<%= pkg.src %>/assets/js/modules/**/*.js',
  '<%= pkg.src %>/assets/js/lib/jquery/plugins/jquery-hse/**/*.js',
  '!<%= pkg.src %>/assets/js/**/*.min.js'
]
```

This fixed the issue!